# Query array using whereHas

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I want to filter products by category (manyToMany relationship). Basically the user select which categories to show. The categories I want to filter are in `$request->keywords`. This is what I tried:

```
  $products = Product::all();
  foreach($request->keywords as $keyword) {
    $products = Product::whereHas('categories', function($q) use ($keyword){
      $q->where('title', '=', $keyword);
    })->get();
  }

  return response()->json($products);
```

The problem is that this does not get all the categories, only the products with the last category in the array. I guess at this point: `$q->where('title', '=', $keyword);`, `$q` does not keep the results of the last loop iteration but always deletes the last loop results. 
I also tried the same thing with `$q->orWhere('title', '=', $keyword);`, but that actually doesn't give me any results.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changed your approach to fetch the data,

```
$products = Product::all();
if (!empty($request->keywords)) { // if keywords not empty
    $keyword  = $request->keywords;
    $products = Product::whereHas('categories', function ($q) use ($keyword) {
        $q->whereIn('title', $keyword); // where in for array
    })->get(); // it won't override old data as there is no loop
}

return response()->json($products);
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks so much! So I guess the problem was that I didn't use `whereIn`?

Comment: If you will compare my snippet with yours, you are partially right

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `whereIn` on the title field by passing in your keywords.

```
$products = Product::all();
$titles = [];
foreach($request->keywords as $keyword) {
    $titles[] = $keyword;
}
$products = Product::whereHas('categories', function($q) use ($keyword){
    $q->whereIn('title', $titles);
})->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm improving other persons answer. Below is the filtered code here

```
$builder = new Product;

if($request->filled('keywords')) {  // if keywords key has any value then query will execute.

    $builder = $builder->whereHas('categories', function($q) use ($request){
                        $q->whereIn('title', array_values($request->keywords));
                    });
}

$items = $builder->get();
dd($items);
```

You can try this.